# Discord.py | How to make a bot talk from what you put in input?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to make a bot that says what you put in input so like:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready when you are")
    while True:
       bop = input("")
       await client.say(bop)
```

I have tried doing this in many ways but I cannot get it to work and I cannot find anything online. Help would be very appreciated!

Comment: You would register an `on_message` coroutine that would be called whenever the bot observed a message. [See this example bot from the `discord.py` github](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/guessing_game.py)  Once you're more comfortable with the library, you may want to consider using the commands extension, depending on what you want your bot to do.

Answer (score 0):

`client.say` won't work in the `on_ready` event. It can only be used from commands. See documentation here: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-bot-say-in-other-places-aside-from-commands

So instead, you can use `client.send_message`. This needs to take `channel` as an argument. Below is example code where the input will always be sent to the "general" channel.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready when you are")
    while True:
        bop = input("")
        for server in client.servers:
            for channel in server.channels:
                if channel.name == "general":
                    await client.send_message(channel, bop)
```